# Internet slow only in browsers

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, internet

When using Firefox and Chromium in Xubuntu 16.04, the highest download speed I can achieve in speed tests is around 15Mbps, yet when I use the internet on other apps it's a lot faster. For instance I tried downloading a 1GB torrent and the download speed on average was around 40Mbps (5MB/s), and peaked around 48Mbps (6MB/s).

This happens both on a wireless and wired connection. My wireless card is the RT2790 Wireless 802.11n 1T/2R PCIe and my ethernet is AR8121/AR8113/AR8114 Gigabit.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, but in the speed tests the upload speed is always higher than the download speed, sometimes even double.

Comment: This is normal. Torrents download from many sources using many streams.

Comment: @Pilot6 but surely a speed test shows you the max download speed you can achieve? I ran the speed tests on another laptop running Windows 10 and it managed to peak at 50Mbps, the same as what the torrents could achieve.